# Проблема с плагином JScrollPane

Tags: jscrollpane, jquery, плагин

Установил на сайт плагин, вроде все работает, но есть небольшая проблема - скроллинг появляется всегда - когда надо и когда не надо. Решил эту проблему в лоб - проверил на странице количество определенных элементов - если их меньше, например, 10, то плагин не инициализируется. Но чувствую, что решение не совсем грамотное, есть ли какой-то более правильный подход?

И еще одна проблема - у меня на странице может быть различное количество элементов для прокрутки, соответственно ползунок должен автоматически измениться в размерах, но в пределах определенного диапазона. Я выставляю `{verticalDragMaxHeight: 300, verticalDragMinHeight: 100}`, но у меня выходит, что ползунок всегда размером 300, вне зависимости от количества содержимого. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо проверки кол-ва эл-тов сравнивать height и screen.height. Решение тоже почти в лоб, но с разных девайсов работать верно будет.

Может быть у вас в css явно задана высота? Если нет, приведите пример на jsbin или jsfiddle.
В принципе, можно инициализировать скрипт и применять к эл-ту только после проверки высоты эл-та.

Comment: > Попробуйте вместо проверки кол-ва
> эл-тов сравнивать height и
> screen.height.

Немного не понял как это реализовать и что это дает?

> Может быть у вас в css явно задана
> высота?

Да, явно, но я же должен как-то ограничивать область просмотра.

Comment: Вы пишете "Решил эту проблему в лоб - проверил на странице количество определенных элементов - если их меньше, например, 10, то плагин не инициализируется" вместо этого можно проверять height. Если height < screen.height, не инициализировать jscrollpane.
Возможно я не правильно истолковал ваш второй вопрос. Поясните его. Желательно с примером на jsbin или jsfiddle.

Comment: Я просто не совсем понял суть вашего совета. Если высота элемента с прокруткой меньше высоты просматриваемой области браузера, то инициализировать плагин. Но она у меня всегда меньше...

А по поводу второго вопроса: предположим, у меня есть каталог товаров, каждая категория которого имеет разное количество товаров, соответственно, необходимо, чтобы ползунок был разного размера: мало товаров - ползунок больше, много - меньше, но в пределах нужного мне диапазона. Диапазон я задал, как написал выше, но работает почему-то только максимальная высота (verticalDragMaxHeight).

Comment: 1. Я имел ввиду если height меньше заданного значения. Переглючило, когда писал, извиняюсь.
2. Скрипт автоматически подгоняет высоту скроллера в процентаже так, как он считает нужным. И, видимо, минимальный размер равен или больше вашего максимального. Можно разве что самому написать зависимость размера высоты ползунка от высоты размера страницы, но это уже будет костыль.

Comment: Я имел ввиду если height меньше заданного значения. Переглючило, когда писал, извиняюсь.

1) height - это высота моего блока с прокруткой. А что вы имеете в виду под "заданным значением"? Что-то я все равно не понимаю вас.

2) На самом деле те параметры, которые я привел в теме и являются нужными мне, я только не могу понять, почему работает один из них. Пробовал вставлять различное количество контента в блок с прокруткой и все равно никак.